Помощь в понимание фрагмента из книги по Javascript, тема labeled statement
Всех приветствую! Читаю книгу по javascript, и столкнулся  с таким моментом: "Labeled statements may themselves be labeled. Effectively, this means that any statement may have multiple labels." ("Помеченные операторы можно помечать снова. Фактически это означает, что любой оператор может иметь множество меток."). Внизу предоставлю пример, как я это понял:
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;

  loopName1: loopName2: while (x < 1) {
    while (y < 1) {
      console.log("loop2");
      break loopName1; 
      y++;
    }
    x++;
    console.log("loop1");
  }

т.е одному statement можно дать два имени. Следовательно break loopName1; и break loopName2; - делают одинаковое действие. Пытаясь понять, где можно это использовать - ни к чему не пришел.
От этого возник вопрос: "правильно ли я понял, о чем говорилось в книге?". Если все правильно, то где это можно использовать?

Моё мнение: этот подход лучше навсегда забыть и не использовать..... Да и если заглянуть сейчас в любой код, то этих меток вы вряд ли найдёте.... Это примерно как eval: он есть, но это всё, что следует о нём знать))

@АлексейШиманский очень редко можно использовать во вложенных циклах.

@eccs0103  я не отрицаю что можно это где-то как-то.....но лучше не надо)

Ну... если сравнить) — это как яблоко. Укусить его можно, но за это из рая выгоняют))

Спасибо за ответы! Я понимаю, что нигде не используется и сам редко где видел такое. Это больше не практический интерес, а теоретический. Из категории: "Кто-то создал - интересно зачем".

"зачем" --- затем, что когда-то кому-то было удобно таким образом что-то сделать.... но времена идут, всё меняется

"когда-то кому-то было удобно таким образом что-то сделать" - вот как раз это и было интересно, что с этим делали, потому что сам я не представляю, и не нашел в инете, что с этим можно было сделать. Пока только сошелся на мнении, что для улучшения читаемости кода.


От этого возник вопрос: "правильно ли я понял, о чем говорилось в книге?".

Ты все правильно понял.


let i = 0

test1: test2: while (++i < 4) {
    console.log(i)
    if (i == 1) continue test1
    console.log('Раз')
    if (i == 2) continue test2
    console.log('Два')
}
console.log('Все')




Если все правильно, то где это можно использовать?

Как уже писали в комментариях, метки вообще вряд ли используют... Поскольку в мало каких ЯП метки вообще поддерживаются. Так зачем путать других людей такими возможностями JS.
Суть "перечня" меток к одному оператору - одно и то же "место", на которое будет осуществляться переход. Разница только в идентификаторе метки. Разве что читаемость кода "улучшить". :)

Благодарю! Тоже сошелся во мнении, что это для "улучшения" читаемости кода
